# Pandas dataframe multilevel indexing with concat - why doesn't this work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to concat two DataFrames, then access the concatenated result using the keys I provided.  However, it doesn't seem to work as per the documentation, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["col1", "col2"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 7], [9, 11]], columns=["col1", "col2"])
dfcomb = pd.concat([df0, df1], keys=["df0", "df1"])
dfcomb
Out[82]: 
       col1  col2
df0 0     1     2
    1     3     4
df1 0     5     7
    1     9    11

dfcomb.index
Out[83]: 
MultiIndex([('df0', 0),
            ('df0', 1),
            ('df1', 0),
            ('df1', 1)],
           )
```

So far, so good.  We've got a multilevel index.  Now, according to the documentation:

One of the important features of hierarchical indexing is that you can select data by a “partial” label identifying a subgroup in the data. Partial selection “drops” levels of the hierarchical index in the result in a completely analogous way to selecting a column in a regular DataFrame.

So, I should be able to access the df0 rows using dfcomb["df0"], right?  No!

```
dfcomb["df0"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
 File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\test_updatd_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'df0'
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2):

The `MultiIndex` in `dfcomb` is in the *index*, not the *columns*, so you have to use `.loc[]` instead of just `[]`:

```
>>> dfcomb.loc['df0']
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is indeed working.  I wonder why the example in the official documentation on MultiIndexing doesn't select by row but by columns:

Comment: Will you please send a link?

Comment: df["bar"]
Out[25]: 
second       one       two
A       0.895717  0.805244
B       0.410835  0.813850
C      -1.413681  1.607920

df["bar", "one"]
Out[26]: 
A    0.895717
B    0.410835
C   -1.413681

I was not aware that in this example they intend multiIndexing to refer to the labels rather than indices.  You'd have thought that if index is kind of reserved word in this library they'd find some other way to refer to labels. multilabeling?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

try using loc

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["col1", "col2"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 7], [9, 11]], columns=["col1", "col2"])
dfcomb = pd.concat([df0, df1], keys=["df0", "df1"])
print(dfcomb)

label="df0"
print(dfcomb.loc[label])
```

output

```
 col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
​
```